# How can I keep same the pixel size with ellipse entity in cesium when zoom in/out (like point)

Tags: entity, cesiumjs

When zooming the view in or out, some entities will zoom in or out (like the ellipse, polyline, ...). But point and billboard will keep the fixed pixel size.

How can I make the zooming entities (ellipse graphics) keep pixel size? Or do some transfrom to make it?

Comment: Maybe make a billboard with an ellipse on it?  A normal ellipse in Cesium has a physical size, not a screen-space size.  Physical sizes will always visually appear to change when the camera zooms around.

Comment: I know what's you mean, but I want find a method to transform the positions(Transfrom the screen pixel size to radius, or some like that) by hand. Did you know how to do it?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some screenshots showing what you would like?